# Manipulate Excel's today() function to read date and time

Tags: excel, excel-formula, logic

In a excel table column that I have in a table the date & times are given.

```
3/16/16 18:47
3/16/16 5:20
3/15/16 16:11
3/14/16 9:12
3/14/16 9:05
3/14/16 8:56
3/14/16 6:25
3/14/16 4:21
3/14/16 2:06
3/11/16 13:03
```

On another Sheet, Sheet1... I am trying to take the user's input to see how many day's in the past from today to count the amount of dates of the row contain the data needed.

```
=COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!J:J,"<"&TODAY(),'Sheet1'!B:B,"blocker")-COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!J:J,"<"&TODAY()-F14,'Sheet1'!B:B,"blocker")
```

The issue that I am specifically having is that when 1 has been input by the user it won't give the data for TODAY.

I ran some test and found that TODAY() cannot take the date & time only it can only take date... I have to keep the date time format on the table so what would be a way around this?

Comment: So instead of `TODAY()` use `NOW()`

Comment: NOW() gives "current" date and time as to where if the time is off, it wont take the argument.

Comment: So if the user puts 1 in F14 you want everything from today and yesterday?

Comment: So 1 would be today, 2 would be yesterday etc..

Comment: Ah okay, So `TODAY()` does have a time value it is `00:00:00` so change your formula to `=COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!J:J,"<"&TODAY()+1,'Sheet1'!B:B,"blocker")-COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!J:J,"<"&TODAY()-F14+1,'Sheet1'!B:B,"blocker")`  This will make it anything less than 24:00:00 today and 24:00:00 of the day F14 from today.

Comment: Oh man, Scott... Thank you for you help. I didn't think today took time at all. Thank you so much.